# breaking line inside of html tag due to long attributes

Tags: html

From time to time I encounter a problem where I need to break single html tag to multiple lines (e.g. when I have many attributes and the tag is nested). How to format this tag to have it whole visible on screen and in the same time don't have a messy code.

My current solution is this:

```html
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-default btn-block"
    data-username="John Doe"
    data-userid="d8nasd98asn9d8sado9n8aso9d8nsado98sa9d8nso9ad8a"
    ...
>
    Show
</button>
```

But it doesn't look very elegant.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, I think that's the most elegant solution available.  I agree it'd be nice to have an alternative, but when you have many attributes (particularly in a framework that utilizes attributes on elements like Angular) then this is actually much more readable, even though it doesn't feel very HTML-like.

Comment: I keep the first attribute on the first line, align each attribute flush with the first one, and keep the final `>` at the end of the last attribute. But this is all opinion based. Write it however you like it, it doesn't matter to the HTML parser.